# Updating a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as such

```
col.1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "b", "c")
col.2 <- c(22, 33, 55, 66, 66, 22, 54)
df <- data.frame(col.1, col.2)
```

and I would like to update `col.2` to 100 when the `df$col.1` matches the `search.df`

```
search.df <- c("b", "d")
```

In fact I have `dataframe` of 1k+ rows and my `search.df` has 16 elements. I know some SQL and I can't find a straightforward update in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[df[,1] %in% search.df, 2] <- 100
```

or if you want to use column elements of the data frame directly

```
df$col.2[df$col.1 %in% search.df] <- 100
```

For simplicity, the same broken down:

```
# get index of rows to be updated by checking each value 
# in col1 against search.df => e.g. FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, ...
index <- df[,1] %in% search.df

# update col2 where index is TRUE to a new value
df[index, 2] <- 100
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), set the 'key' column as 'col.1', subset the rows with 'search.df', and assign (`:=`) the corresponding values of 'col.2' to 100.  It should be fast for big datasets as we are replacing in place.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df, key='col.1')[search.df, col.2 := 100]
df
#    col.1 col.2
#1:     a    22
#2:     b   100
#3:     b   100
#4:     c    55
#5:     c    54
#6:     d   100
#7:     e    66
```